# How to launch a windows application when "Target" and "Start in" fields are different

Tags: windows, automation, shortcuts, run-dialog

I am writing automation scripts and to start windows application I use <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> shortcut. However I have a problem with applications which has different data in "Start in" and "Target".

Obviously using only what appears in "Target" won't always work.

How can I run such application from Run dialog window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just realized that I can use a direct link to the shortcut itself and start it from the run window. It seems the most straightforward way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could write a small batch file which accepts the target as an argument. Your batch file can change directory to target and call your script from that folder with full path. Since you're the developer, you can implement this feature inside your script too IMHO.

I'm not using windows for these tasks for a long time but, it should look like this.

- Assuming the target directory exists on the same drive that is passed to the batch file automatically
- Script call: `myscript.bat <target_directory_to_work_on>`
- Script should contain lines like the following:

  ```
  cd "%1"
  c:\my\script\directory\my_tool.exe
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure how the final syntax should look like. How the resulting command should look like?

Comment: @EugeneS, I've Updates the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I have just simulated these 2 steps in cmd: 1. `cd` to path which appears in "Start in" field. 2.While there, paste whatever appears in "Target" field. However I still end up with an error. When I run the app using the shortcut, it runs fine.

Comment: What appears in the target? I'm not using windows for a long time. My memory doesn't serve me well...

Comment: The target is an exe file and there is few configuration files in the "Start in" directory.

Comment: I have just realized that I can simply use the link to shortcut itself and thus avid unnecessary workarounds. I think that I will stay with that. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, that's nice. You're welcome! Happy hacking!

Comment: @EugeneS, Also if you can write it as an answer and accept that, you can help everyone & "That would be great." :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, can't you rewrite the application and design it the right way (in your case is to look in the same folder)?

As another solution, you can get a utility (one file) called `junction` and then create a batch file where you link current directory with another directory.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx